# Map subtask_id to TaskManager in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an operator with parallelism=256 running on 128 task managers. Each time when I get a checkpoint failure, it happens at the same subtask of this operator, for example it's always subtask 129 that gets stuck and blocks the checkpointing. I want to understand what happened to this subtask by examining logs of the task manager that subtask 129 is running on. Is there a way in Flink to map subtask id to the corresponding Task Manager?

Answer (score 2):

The `taskmanager.log` files contain the names of the deployed tasks including their sub task index. You could simply search for the `TASK_NAME (129/256)` in all `taskmanager.log` files.

Comment: Thank you @TillRohrmann. Is there a programmatic way to find that. In my case I will have to check all the 128 TM logs.

Comment: If you use a central logging system like logstash for example this should be easy. Alternatively, if you deploy on Yarn, you could activate log aggregation which gives you an aggregated log over all components.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out a way  to map the subtask id to container id by querying the Flink specific metrics.

Comment: @YueLiu could you please explain the way you achieved that ?

Comment: @YueLiu . I am also looking a way to map a subtaskID to a specific TaskManager. Could you explain your approach for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find not a trivial, but working solution to get the required map at runtime programmatically.

The main idea is that the Rest Endpoint [/jobs/:jobid/vertices/:vertexid](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/ops/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-vertices-vertexid) provides the necessary information for a specific vertex in format

```json
{
  "id": "804e...",
  "name": "Map -> Sink",
  ...
  "subtasks": [
    {
      "subtask": 0,
      "host": "ip-10-xx-yy-zz:36ddd"
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

The main difficulty was to get the web interface url programmatically. I was able to get it this way (probably, there is a more elegant solution):

```scala
val env = FieldUtils
      .readField(getRuntimeContext.asInstanceOf[StreamingRuntimeContext], "taskEnvironment", true)
      .asInstanceOf[RuntimeEnvironment]

    try {
      println("trying to get cluster client...")
      val client = new RestClusterClient[String](env.getTaskManagerInfo.getConfiguration, "rest")
      return client.getWebInterfaceURL

    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        println("Failed to get cluster client : ")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Given the web interface url, I simply made an http call to it and constructed the map.